# How to use dependency injection correctly? Because using methods of injected class creates new dependency

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I'm a self-learner, trying to become a good PHP developer and want to fully understand Dependency Injection.

I understand the broad principle, in theory dependency injection makes my classes not have tightly coupled dependencies to other classes.

But I don't understand how this can be fully implemented in practice.

Example using the PHP League Container and an Example Controller:

```
/***************************************************************************************
 * DI Container setup
 ***************************************************************************************/
$container = new Container();

/***************************************************************************************
 * Register Service Providers
 ***************************************************************************************/
$container->addServiceProvider(new \App\Providers\ConfigProvider);

/***************************************************************************************
 * Register Container Class Dependencies
 ***************************************************************************************/
$container->share('App\Http\Controller')
    ->withArguments(['config']);
```

Now in my controller I would receive the injected dependency like this:

```
class Controller
{

    public $config;

    function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    function index()
    {
        $newConfigItem = 'domain.com';
        $configDomain = $this->config->setConfig($newConfigItem);
    }
}
```

The Controller is just an example, it could be any class, any type of class like maybe a Serviceprovider, Middleware etc.

**This is more a general question regarding the correct handling of dependency injection.**

**Doesn't using the setConfig() method of the injected Config class creates a new tightly coupled dependency?**

Even if I would use the Container to create a new Object, using the container directly in any class just created a dependency to the container method used to register / extend Objects in the Container.

Or do I need an extra layer of PHP classes that somehow wrap my dependencies to use new method names, but even then this extra layer of php classes has then dependencies that need adjusting if I need to switch out libraries/packages/components used.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking?

Comment: I think you picked a bad example with a configuration.  I like to think of configurations as being immutable.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I try not to pass the container about, I use it upfront and very early.

Comment: Well, I mentioned it's an example, the question targets the principle of DI and not the code in particular.

Comment: But how would you then ever use methods of the Objects residing in the Container, in other Classes that need them? :)

Comment: The objects that require dependencies have them passed to them.  The objects have declaired dependencies, they don't fetch them from the container.

Comment: Do you have a code example for this? I don't follow what you're saying, in my example I also don't fetch it from the container directly, but use the method through the passed property dependency. But this still creates a new dependency on the used method setConfig()